# Disable TLS 1.0 & 1.1 OR only use TLS 1.2 and greater in Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, security, ssl, server

How can I block TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on my Node.js Express server? I'm using a traditional server setup script:

```
const app = express();
export const server = app.listen(3000);
```

I'm slightly confused why I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a specific TLS version with \`node-fetch\` like TLS v1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207601/how-do-i-use-a-specific-tls-version-with-node-fetch-like-tls-v1-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you will be running your Express server behind something else, like an Nginx proxy, an AWS Load Balancer, or some other piece of software or hardware that terminates TLS. In your example, you're not listening over HTTPS at all, you're listening for HTTP connections on port 3000. The configuration would usually be done outside of your Node app, but if you do want to do it in your Node app, it would be like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const { options } = require('crypto')
const app = express()

const opts = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/chain.pem'),
  secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
}

// other app logic

// Or 443 if you run it as root, which is not recommended;
// instead you should proxy to it.
https.createServer(opts, app).listen(3443)
```

Comment: Thanks @Zac! Do you have any documentation pointing to how it's preferable to block lower TLS versions through our load balancer vs. directly on our node app?

Comment: This depends on your environment and if you have compliance needs, but here are some related questions on stackoverflow: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/should-ssl-be-terminated-at-a-load-balancer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027582/application-load-balancer-elbv2-ssl-pass-through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492117/where-to-terminate-ssl-tls-in-node-nginx. But of course if you're running a small or low traffic app and don't want to deal with a load balancer or reverse proxy, Node can totally do it, It's just not ideal for prod workloads.

Comment: Awesome, this is very helpful! Thanks @Zac

Comment: You are trying to modify `const option` and it throws compile time error. I believe there is a typo, could you please correct this.

Answer (score 1):

ex.

```
const https = require("https");
const https_options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../ssl/cert.pfx")), 
  passphrase: "password",
  minVersion: "TLSv1.2"
}

server = https.createServer(https_options, app);
```

minVersion is the easiest way to accomplish this as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62051684/4487632

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637737/6503439) has a typo as Aditya Acharya suggested, but I have no reputation to directly comment on it. The line

```
const { options } = require('crypto')
```

should be

```
const { constants } = require('crypto')
```

instead, otherwise the references to `constants` in

```
secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
```

would all be invalid.