# Node js express server on GCP VM giving SSL error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm trying to access an express.js node server I'm hosting on GCP and I'm getting this error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
<server ip> sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I looked at another stack overflow answer and they said to edit `default-allow-internal` in the network tab to allow all, my network tab looks like this now:
[image]

My server starts fine and I know the logic inside works (it contains a scraper that logs to the console every time it runs and I can see it's succeeding there) But I can't access it via it's external IP `https://<ip>:8000`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your relevant SSL config?

Comment: I haven't done anything with SSL for this VM, mainly the reason for this question. Do you know of any sources that explain how to set this up? If it helps I own a domain via google domains that has a valid SSL certificate linked to it.

Comment: You have a lot of options. If you want to terminate ssl at your server, you could do it as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637645/disable-tls-1-0-1-1-or-only-use-tls-1-2-and-greater-in-node-js-express/65637737#65637737). I usually recommend setting up Nginx (or Caddy, or some other proxy server) though. Or, if you're okay with paying a little bit more to GCP, the ideal option would be to use a [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/). Since your cert was provisioned through Google, that might be the easiest option, as well.

Answer (score 2):

As @Zac Anger suggested the easiest option is to use Load Balancer for terminating SSL at your server.

As given in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/):

> HTTP(S) load balancing can balance HTTP and HTTPS traffic across
> multiple backend instances, across multiple regions. Your entire app
> is available via a single global IP address, resulting in a simplified
> DNS setup. HTTP(S) load balancing is scalable, fault-tolerant,
> requires no pre-warming, and enables content-based load balancing. For
> HTTPS traffic, it provides SSL termination and load balancing.

To terminate SSL follow the below steps:

1. Create an instance group that has at least 1 live instance.
2. Create http load balancer with the following:

   1. Upload a SSL certificate.
   2. Create a backend service to point to the instance group. Make sure the protocol is HTTP.
   3. Create a target https proxy with the certificate you uploaded.
   4. Finally, create a global forwarding rule that points HTTPS to the target proxy you created before.